# React Hooks Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a project component that is getting data from my Project context. And I'm trying to select the first object in that array of objects and pass it to a new state.

**Project Component**

```
const projects = useContext(ProjectContext) // array of objects from context
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({}) // where i will pass projects[0]
const selectProj = (data) => {
    setSelected(data) // INFINITE LOOP ERROR
}

if (projects.length > 0) {
    selectProj(projects[0])
}
```

So I'm kinda lost here on what todo.

**Update: Answer I Used**

```
const projects = useContext(ProjectContext) // array of objects
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({})

const selectProj = (data) => {
    setSelected(data)
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (projects.length > 0) {
        selectProj(projects[0])
    }
}, [projects])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting into an infinite loop because `setSelected` causes a re-render, and on the re-render `projects.length` is greater than 0 again, which causes another re-render, and so on.

One way to avoid this is by calling `selectProj` only if there's no project already selected:

```
if (!selected && projects.length > 0) {
  selectProj(projects[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked. and there's another answer I used useEffect and put my conditional statement there its not throwing an error anymore.

Comment: Your solution would not actually work because selected is initialized as `{}` so it would never be false. Maybe the following would work: `if (projects.length > 0 && !projects.includes(selected)) {`

Answer (score 2):

don't change state on render, you can do it in `useEffect` or give a initial value

```
useEffect(()=> {
   setSelected(projects[0])
}, [])
```

or

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(projects[0]);
```

Comment: This answer is the correct approach but both your answer will throw an error, Because you didnt check if projects is empty or not